Hardhat Node Does Not Show Accounts and Private Keys
I am working with a Hardhat project, and I'm having trouble accessing the default accounts and private keys when running the Hardhat node. I have configured my hardhat.config.js file to use Hardhat's default accounts, but the accounts are not being displayed in the terminal when I start the node.
Here is my hardhat.config.js file:
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");
require("solidity-coverage");
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify");

const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || "";
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL || "";
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "";
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || "";

module.exports = {
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts",
  },
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://localhost:8545",
    },
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
    },
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.27",
      },
      {
        version: "0.8.0",
      },
    ],
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: true,
    currency: "USD",
    outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
    noColors: true,
    coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    token: "MATIC",
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0, // Use first account as deployer by default
    },
  },
  sourcify: {
    enabled: true,
  },
};

Steps I've Taken:
I've started the Hardhat node using npx hardhat node.
The node starts successfully and shows contract deployments in the terminal.
However, no accounts are displayed, and the node does not show the default Hardhat accounts and private keys.
Here is the terminal output:
Nothing to compile
localnetwork network identified 
deploying "MockV3Aggregator" (tx: 0xf40c770ab84bc574202efad27896a28f7675534ff6e30f7cb23b8d234233f930)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 694833 gas
mocks deployed
---------------------------------------------------------------
deploying "Fundme" (tx: 0x4ee9ff6dc0cc5b8df7aeab630f979e0f1007b03796a7a535b6f81092a2406fb6)...: deployed at 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 with 1034332 gas
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Started HTTP and WebSocket JSON-RPC server at http://127.0.0.1:8545/

When running npx hardhat node, I expect to see the list of pre-generated accounts and their private keys, but they are not showing up in the terminal.
I Have Tried:
1.I have ensured that my hardhat.config.js file is correctly configured withn namedAccounts.
2.I have tried restarting the node and re-running the command.
3.I have checked the output to ensure there are no errors.

Happy to get on a call and help with this.
